# When is "modified" used on the /questions page?

Tags: support, questions

I had a tab open on https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions, while I was writing a question on another tab. (I didn't notice I had two tabs open on the same site; probably a tab was open to a different Stack Exchange site, I was notified of a new comment/answer, and I clicked on the notification to read the full comment/answer.)
When I wrote the question, I checked the other tab to see if new questions were asked, and I found a box telling me that a new question was asked. When I clicked on that box, a new question was shown in the page, but I noticed that the question (mine) was reported to be modified, while I created it. My previous question was reported as *asked*.

[image: screenshot]

In which cases the questions on https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions are shown as *modified*, instead of *asked*? I thought the questions on that page should always show *asked*. This is the first time I saw modified on the question page. Even on other Stack Exchange sites, I have never read *modified*.

Comment: I can't find any consistent pattern.  I checked earlier and thought JLU had both *modified* and *asked*, but right now **all** questions on JLU show up as *modified*, even if they've never been edited!  And now I see only *asked* on ELL, even though I saw both earlier.  I really have no clue.

Answer (score 1):

*The question is old, but I think others can benefit from it even so.*

There's a userscript at Stack Apps that tells you precisely what the activity that bumped the question was. It's called [Stack Activity](https://stackapps.com/questions/4134/stack-activity-last-activity-of-every-question), and it works across all Stack Exchange sites.

[image: Image shamelessly "stolen" from the Stack Apps post]

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure but I added a tag "word-usage" to your question.  Perhaps that was the reason it was being shown as modified.

Comment: On that page, _modified_ is never used, even when somebody edits the question after it is asked. That is what I noticed in other Stack Exchange sites. Or it is the JavaScript code that wrongly uses _modified_ instead of _asked_, or there is a reason to show _modified_. (It could be the code has been recently changed because it has been decided _modified_ should be shown in specific cases.)

Comment: Or may be because you were editing it? I am just guessing here! :)